# Get the Time from now() function in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, time

I have a store function.

I want to get only the time from the `now()` function in Postgres. How Can i do it?

I know that for the date you can use `DATE(now())`, but for the time I tried `TIME(now())`, but it does not work.

Comment: You could just use `current_time`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of extracting it from `now` you could just use the builtin field:

```
SELECT CURRENT_TIME
```

Comment: and how can I extract it from the now() function

Comment: @juanpscotto: you don't, it's a separate function that only returns the time.

Answer (score 3):

CURRENT_TIME returns the current time with timezone, LOCALTIME returns the time without timezone information. You can specify the precision:

```
SELECT CURRENT_TIME(0);
SELECT LOCALTIME(0);
```

Another way is to use to_char() and format the time the way you want it:

```
SELECT to_char(NOW(), 'HH24:MI:SS');
```